# Booting a virtual os on a physical environment

Tags: virtual-machine

Is there an application that allows you to add a virtualized version of your operating system into the mbr?
By virtualized, I mean that if you boot this one, any changes made in it will not be committed to the disk. Just like how deepfreeze, returnil, and shadow user works.
Is it possible to do that?
Because the applications mentioned above requires you to reboot if you want that changes will not be retained.

Comment: so when you say "into the mbr" are you trying to native boot a vm.

Comment: nope, not really a vm. The physical os itself. But in a sandboxed state wherein any changes made disappears after reboot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or something that you can choose from at boot through a boot loader like GRUB?

If you are wanting the latter, than you could install your OS on a USB stick and then boot from that, then the changes will only exist on the USB stick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: would it be slower if I try to boot from usb stick

Comment: It may be faster (as in data read/write) seeing as how it would be solid state.

Comment: And also, all writes would be contained on the USB stick but you can also access the main Hard Drive from the USB stick's OS to transfer documents and such.

Comment: Did this work?.

Comment: USB flash drives are much slower than hard drives. Though "solid state", they write very slowly and data has to be processed to prevent writing to the same spot in memory since writes can only be done several hundred times before the medium fails.